# Count Queries slow down with increased number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following structure of tables:

tb_Students

```
CustomerId  StudentId  StudentName
 1             1        Michael
 1             2        Sam
 2             1        Declan
```

tb_Contact_Detail

```
StudentId ContactId CustomerId ContactName Relation
  1          1         1         Rory      Father
  1          2         1         Rachel    Mother
```

tb_Channel

```
ChannelId  ChannelName
   1        Emergency
   2        GeneralInfo
```

tb_Contact_Channel_Mapping

```
CustomerId ChannelId StudentId ContactId
   1         1         1          2
   1         2         1          2
   1         2         1          1
```

tb_Contact_Fields

```
CustomerId ContactId ContactType(Phone/SMS/Email)
   1         1          Phone
   1         1          Email
   1         1          SMS
   1         2          Email
   1         2          SMS


SELECT @EmailCnt = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN field.FieldType = 'Email' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0),
       @PhoneCnt = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN field.FieldType = 'Phone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0),
       @SMSCnt = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN field.FieldType = 'SMS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0)
FROM tb_Students stu WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN tb_Contact_Detail det WITH (NOLOCK) ON stu.CustomerId = det.CustomerId
                                                   AND stu.StudentId = det.StudentId
     INNER JOIN tb_Contact_Channel_Mapping map WITH (NOLOCK) ON det.CustomerId = map.CustomerId
                                                            AND det.StudentId = map.StudentId
                                                            AND det.ContactId = map.ContactId
     INNER JOIN tb_Contact_Fields field WITH (NOLOCK) ON det.CustomerId = field.CustomerId
                                                     AND det.ContactId = map.ContactId
WHERE stud.CustomerId = @CustomerId
  AND map.ChannelId = @ChannelId;

For ChannelId=1, CustomerCode=1
Result id EmailCount 2, PhoneCount 1, SMSCount 2
```

This query is being frequently used throughout multiple workflows. However issue now observed is that as the records of students and contacts and channels is increasing the results of this query slow down and time out. Is there any performance improvement or alternatives can be suggested for the same?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using `NOLOCK` against every table? I hope *" results of this query slow down and time out."* isn't the reason; as it's more than likely going to make your results wrong, not faster.

Comment: Not a performance thing but careful splattering NOLOCK everywhere. It is not a magic go fast button. It has some very serious side affects. Things like randomly returning missing and/or duplicate rows. There is a whole litany of other "fun" things that hint can do. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: look at the query execution plan, see if it suggests adding any keys or indexes.

Comment: For the task at hand, yes the query will slow down as more rows are added. My guess is that you don't have a good indexing strategy here. Perhaps you can share the execution plan? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: *"to avoid locking of tables"* That isn't what `NOLOCK` does.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase NOLOCK was added, for quick reads so that reads not be waiting on completion of other operations

Comment: Execution plan did suggest couple of nonclustered keys however which I added. This did not help much,  tb_Contact_Fields table has grown with large data set and taking time.  
I understand this has limited options but just thought if SUM or any other operation can be done efficiently to save time

Comment: Are you aware that nolock can also lead to corrupt results, especially when others are updating the tables?

Comment: Have you tried excluding records via WHERE ...field.FieldType IN('Email', 'Phone','SMS') possibly with FieldType in an index somewhere - only those records do anything in the final output

Comment: SUM isn't what is causing performance issues. It is the joins almost certainly. And just adding suggested indexes rarely results in anything good. Those suggestions are actually worse about as often as they help. It seems like you could possibly even skip the Student table entirely here.

Comment: I have simplified here but the contact_details is generic table used by teachers, admin and students so definitely student id to join is needed to get students.

Comment: *"Execution plan did suggest couple of nonclustered keys however which I added."* The recommendations aren't *always* right. Why not share the plan with us, like asked? It'll make things far easier.

Comment: I have created similar tables can't share company code hence the issue.

Comment: Then, perhaps, it's time to hire a consultant, @DeeP .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT @EmailCnt = ISNULL(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN field.FieldType = 'Email'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END), 0)
    ,@PhoneCnt = ISNULL(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN field.FieldType = 'Phone'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END), 0)
    ,@SMSCnt = ISNULL(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN field.FieldType = 'SMS'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END), 0)
FROM tb_Students stu WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN tb_Contact_Detail det WITH (NOLOCK) ON stu.CustomerId = det.CustomerId
    AND stu.StudentId = det.StudentId
INNER JOIN tb_Contact_Channel_Mapping map WITH (NOLOCK) ON det.CustomerId = map.CustomerId
    AND det.StudentId = map.StudentId
    AND det.ContactId = map.ContactId
INNER JOIN tb_Contact_Fields field WITH (NOLOCK) ON det.CustomerId = field.CustomerId
    AND field.FieldType IN (
        'Email'
        ,'Phone'
        ,'SMS'
        )
WHERE stud.CustomerId = @CustomerId
    AND map.ChannelId = @ChannelId
```

Here, the second 'AND det.ContactId = map.ContactId' I'm not understanding the need for that because the logic exists in another JOIN.  Additionally, I'm only joining to the 'FieldType' of interest.  You may want to check if that can be aided with an index

I hope it helps.

Comment: Cato, let me try both of the suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Cato this did help a bit as I have 6 options this did provide some improvement.

Comment: @DeeP, well observe by Cato.Earlier it was trying to fetch more record than require so it was slow.now only it return require resultset so it has to be improvement.If you need further improvement then you hv to mention no. of record in each table.Existing index,datatype that is use in join etc.